# How to Center Chrome App Window on Screen?

Tags: centering

The main.js (event page) file does not support percentage values like this:

'bounds': {
            'width' : 800,
            'height': 696,
            'left': 50%,
            'top' : 50%
        },

Nor does chrome.app.window indicate any such means to do so using configuration parameters. So how do we center the event page when the event page app window is launched?

Answer (score 0):

You need to calculate the absolute coordinates.
This example creates a new window 80% the size of the available screen space and centers it:

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
  chrome.app.window.create('appstart.html', {
    'id' : 'mainWindow',
    'state' : 'normal',
    'bounds' : {
        'width': Math.round(window.screen.availWidth*0.8),
        'height': Math.round(window.screen.availHeight*0.8),
        'left' : Math.round((window.screen.availWidth-(window.screen.availWidth*0.8))/2),
        'top' : Math.round((window.screen.availHeight-(window.screen.availHeight*0.8))/2)
    }
  });
});
```